# Get the value after = in a given string using regular Expression

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

I have two strings as given below:

```
$String1="Variable Value: PTSPT ID= 12.5 PTSPA ID= 14.5"

$String2="Little GID=7375678 Coverity Client=t-i-kjo-1"
```

I want to get the value `12.5` if I pass the string `"PTSPT ID"`, `14.5` for `"PTSPA ID"`, `7375678` for `"Little GID"`, and `t-i-kjo-1` for `"Coverity Client"`.

I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
$myString1 = $String1.substr($String1.indexOf("PTSPT ID=") + 1)
$myString2 = $String1.substr($String1.indexOf("PTSPA ID=") + 1)
$myString3 = $String2.substr($String2.indexOf("Little GID=") + 1)
$myString4 = $String2.substr($String2.indexOf("Coverity Client=") + 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using regex. The `$val` variable can be the user input

```
$string1
Variable Value: PTSPT ID= 12.5 PTSPA ID= 14.5
$string2
Little GID=7375678 Coverity Client=t-i-kjo-1
$val = "PTSPT ID"
[regex]::Matches( $String1 , "(?<=$val=\s*)[^\s]+" )  | select -expa value
12.5
$val = "PTSPA ID"
[regex]::Matches( $String1 , "(?<=$val=\s*)[^\s]+" )  | select -expa value
14.5
$val = "Little GID"
[regex]::Matches( $String2 , "(?<=$val=\s*)[^\s]+" )  | select -expa value
7375678
$val = "Coverity Client"
[regex]::Matches( $String2 , "(?<=$val=\s*)[^\s]+" )  | select -expa value
t-i-kjo-1
```

edit after comment:

this is a little comment on the regex but is not but is no exhaustive ABSOLUTLY ;)

**(?<=**$val=\s***)**    -> is a look-behind assertion: look for '$val= '

[^\s]            -> match everything but not white space

+                -> match at least once the previous match

Comment: Can you please give a brief description of (?<=$val=\s*)[^\s]+.I am not good in regex

Comment: @user1654136 I suggest to take a look here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/.